# How to format use interface with Observable data

Tags: angular, observable

```
login() {
  this.authenticationService.login(this.account)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        const token: Token = data;
      }
    )
}
```

I'm getting `Cannot assign type Token to type Object`.
Ideally I would like to do `const token: Token = data.token;` but I'm also getting an error : `property 'token' does not exist on type Object` even though the data actually has the token property.

How can I make `const token: Token = data.token;` works or eventually `const token: Token = data;` in Angular 5?

Here is the login method in AuthenticationService class :

```
login(account: Account) {
    return this.http.post(AuthenticateAPI,
        {
            email: account.email,
            password: account.password,
            platformId: account.platformId
        });
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of your type definitions, if data type is not provided, it is assumed that you have an Observable of Object, and Object in typescript has no own properties, but you can do this, if you are sure about your data type:

```
login() {
  this.authenticationService.login(this.account)
.subscribe(
  (data: {token: Token}) => { // provide the data type explicitly
    const token: Token = data.token; // safely use your object
    }
  )
}
```